# What is the keycode for "Shift + Arrow key"?

Tags: jquery, events, keycode

I want to write a script which triggers an artificial keydown event (Shift + Arrow key) when button is clicked in jQuery.

```
$('button').click(function(){

   $('body').trigger(jQuery.Event('keydown', {keycode:16})); //This line triggers a keydown for 'Shift'.//

   $('body').trigger(jQuery.Event('keydown', {keycode:38})); //This line triggers a keydown for 'Up Arrow key'.//


});
```

Is there a way to combain these two? That is, is there a key code for 'Shift + Arrow key' or any script for this to be done? I would appreciate any responses. Thank you.

Comment: Attempting to trigger user keystrokes seems pretty menacing...

Comment: Are you sure you can't just directly call whatever function would get trigerred by said keypress? Most of the time this is better then triggering keystrokes.

Comment: Yes, but I want users to be able to operate an application just by a mouse instead of having them press keys(Shift + Arrow).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `shiftKey` property indicates that the shift key is pressed:

```
$('body').trigger(jQuery.Event('keydown', { keycode:38, shiftKey: true }));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just tried the above line and it works!!

Comment: @AkioYanagawa - glad to hear it - best of luck